# Switch in Drawer Navigation bar

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

I put Switch in menu item of Drawer navigation bar with this :
[image]

[image]

but when i try to access Switch in activity Oncreate with this code

```
        NavigationView  navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

    try {

        ((Switch) navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_isactive).getActionView()).setChecked(true);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

i Got cast error :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuItemImpl cannot be cast to android.widget.Switch
```

and on ex.getMessage() tell me : Cant not cast linearLayout to Switch?!!

Comment: if you add your code as pictures, it's very hard for others to help you debug, because we can't copy paste it.

Comment: i dont know why when i paste code here or paste in Code part  it didnt show all my code and just show part of it that why i put image of code here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

finaly i find answer and i put it here for others

```
    NavigationView  navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);


MenuItem menuItem = navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_isactive); // This is the menu item that contains your switch
Switch drawer_switch = (Switch) menuItem.getActionView().findViewById(R.id.m_swisactive);
drawer_switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        // Your logic goes here
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.valueOf(isChecked), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```